# Value for Json Output of a property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my model:

```
public class Model {

    (...)

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Created By")]
    public UserProfile CreatedBy { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Changed By")]
    public UserProfile ChangedBy { get; set; }

}
```

I want the output these fields to be the Username property within the UserProfile class. Right now, when doing a simple JSON output it just outputs

```
CreatedBy: null
ChangedBy null
```

(I tried overriding the ToString() method on the UserProfile class to return the username but that did not help.)

How can I make it so that when outputting it in json, I get the Username field value?

This is how I am outputting the data in json:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{

    public List<Model> Get(string param1, string param2)
    {

        DbContext db = new DbContext();

        List<Model> list = (from d in db.Models
                               select d
                               ).ToList();


        return list;

    }
}
```

Comment: The default Json Serializer already do this for you. Looks like you are not including this fields when you are getting it from the DB. You should post more code!

Comment: I added the code for the ApiController to my original post. let me know what else you would require me to show.

Comment: Still struggling with this.. no idea how to display the Username property of the UserProfile class...

Answer (score 0):

First, you must return ActionResult/JsonResult to get the Json out.

```
public ActionResult GetJson()
{
     var result=from m in db.Models select new { CreatedBy=m.CreatedBy.Name, ChangedBy=m.ChnangedBy.Name };
     return Json(result, JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet)
}
```